# Append list items by number of hyphens available

Tags: python

```
mylist = [('country', 'NN'), ('shoot', 'NN-DT-PPL'), ('threats', 'NN-JJ'), ('both','RB-JJ-NN'), ('during', 'NN-VBD-JJ-RB'), ('former', 'NN-RB'), ('school', 'NN-CC-JJ-DT'), 
    ('teacher', 'NN-VBZ-PPL-JJ-DT'), ('receive', 'VBZ'), ('batman', 'NN-IN-ABX-CD-RB')]
```

I have a list called mylist. It consists of tuples with the word and their random tags. I do not want to use reg-ex. The minimum tag is 1 and maximum tag is 5. I want to have 5 different lists as per the number of tags.

For one tag tuple, I tried this:

`one=[]
for i in mylist:
    if '-' not in i[1]:
    one.append(i)
print one`

which prints `[('country', 'NN'), [('receive', 'VBZ')` correctly.

For second tag, I wish to print `[('threats', 'NN-JJ'), [('former', 'NN-RB')`

and so on for third, fourth and fifth tag set. I am not able to figure out how to do this.

My actual file has `n` number of tags and it consists of about 10 million words and their tags. Is there any way through which we can know which word has the maximum distinct tags?

It will be of great help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` to organize the data and `.count` to count the number of `-`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

mylist = [('country', 'NN'), ('shoot', 'NN-DT-PPL'), ... ]
res = defaultdict(list)

for item, tags in mylist:
    res[tags.count('-') + 1].append((item, tags))
```

You can print the result with the following code.

```
for k, v in res.items():
    print(str(k) + ": " + str(v))
```

prints:

```
brunsgaard@archbook /tmp> python test2.py
1: [('country', 'NN'), ('receive', 'VBZ')]
2: [('threats', 'NN-JJ'), ('former', 'NN-RB')]
3: [('shoot', 'NN-DT-PPL'), ('both', 'RB-JJ-NN')]
4: [('during', 'NN-VBD-JJ-RB'), ('school', 'NN-CC-JJ-DT')]
5: [('teacher', 'NN-VBZ-PPL-JJ-DT'), ('batman', 'NN-IN-ABX-CD-RB')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Other way of doing this

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter


a=[('country', 'NN'), ('shoot', 'NN-DT-PPL'), ('threats', 'NN-JJ'), ('both','RB-JJ-NN'), ('during', 'NN-VBD-JJ-RB'), ('former', 'NN-RB'), ('school', 'NN-CC-JJ-DT'),
    ('teacher', 'NN-VBZ-PPL-JJ-DT'), ('receive', 'VBZ'), ('batman', 'NN-IN-ABX-CD-RB')]


func=lambda x:len(x[1].split('-'))
for k,g in groupby(sorted(a,key=func),key=func):
    print k,list(g)

#0utput
1 [('country', 'NN'), ('receive', 'VBZ')]
2 [('threats', 'NN-JJ'), ('former', 'NN-RB')]
3 [('shoot', 'NN-DT-PPL'), ('both', 'RB-JJ-NN')]
4 [('during', 'NN-VBD-JJ-RB'), ('school', 'NN-CC-JJ-DT')]
5 [('teacher', 'NN-VBZ-PPL-JJ-DT'), ('batman', 'NN-IN-ABX-CD-RB')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = [('country', 'NN'), ('shoot', 'NN-DT-PPL'), ... ]
res = defaultdict(list)

for item, tags in mylist:
    res[tags.count('-') + 1].append((item, tags))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string using '-' as the separator and count the number of elements in the resultant generated list as follows (for 3 tags) -

```
>>> [t for t in mylist if len(t[1].split('-')) == 3]
[('shoot', 'NN-DT-PPL'), ('both', 'RB-JJ-NN')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maximum dash count would be:

```
max_dash_count = max(i[1].count('-') for i in mylist) + 1
```

However, there are more efficient ways to do this, using dictionaries:

```
dash_dict = dict()
for i in mylist:
    count = i[1].count('-') + 1
    if count in dash_dict:
        dash_dict[count].add(i)
    else:
        dash_dict[count] = [i]
```

Afterward, you're left with a dictionary of lists you can easily iterate over:

```
for count in sorted(dash_dict.keys()):
    print 'Items with ' + str(count) + ' dashes:'
    for i in dash_dict[count]:
        print repr(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

mylist = [('country', 'NN'), ('shoot', 'NN-DT-PPL'), ('threats', 'NN-JJ'), ('both','RB-JJ-NN'), ('during', 'NN-VBD-JJ-RB'), ('former', 'NN-RB'), ('school', 'NN-CC-JJ-DT'), ('teacher', 'NN-VBZ-PPL-JJ-DT'), ('receive', 'VBZ'), ('batman', 'NN-IN-ABX-CD-RB')]
MAX_TAG = 5
def findTag():
   d = {}
   for tup in mylist:
      a,b = tup
      n = b.count('-')
      if not 0 <= n <= MAX_TAG - 1:
         continue
      if n not in d:
         d[n] = []
      d[n].append(tup)

   for k in sorted(d.keys()):
      print '{} => {}'.format(k+1, d[k])
if __name__ == '__main__':
   findTag()

1 => [('country', 'NN'), ('receive', 'VBZ')]
2 => [('threats', 'NN-JJ'), ('former', 'NN-RB')]
3 => [('shoot', 'NN-DT-PPL'), ('both', 'RB-JJ-NN')]
4 => [('during', 'NN-VBD-JJ-RB'), ('school', 'NN-CC-JJ-DT')]
5 => [('teacher', 'NN-VBZ-PPL-JJ-DT'), ('batman', 'NN-IN-ABX-CD-RB')]
```